# How to split value from json String?

Tags: android, json, android-json

I want to split values of json String into multiple string.  I am getting values in "images" thats is (image1, image2, image3) i want to split this string into 3 different strings, I am not getting how i acheive this

```
   protected void status() {

        try {


            JSONArray property_images = new JSONArray(myJSON);

          for(int i=1;i<property_images.length();i++){

                JSONObject c = property_images.getJSONObject(i);
                img = c.getString("images");

             }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is Json Format

```
[{"img_id":"6","listing_id":"1","images":"images (3).jpg","slider_status":"yes","date":"0000-00-00"},{"img_id":"7","listing_id":"1","images":"images (4).jpg","slider_status":"yes","date":"0000-00-00"},{"img_id":"8","listing_id":"1","images":"474harvester2008C-525x328.jpg","slider_status":"yes","date":"0000-00-00"}]
```

Comment: show the JSON atleast

Comment: Do you want to have "images (3).jpg", images (4).jpg" and "474harvester2008C-525x328.jpg" in 3 different Strings?

Comment: Yes i want them in 3 different string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop starts with `1` instead of `0` btw. Other than that you can use a String array to store the image fields.

```
String[] stringArray = new String[property_images.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < property_images.length(); i++) {

JSONObject c = property_images.getJSONObject(i);
stringArray[i] = c.getString("images");

}

for (String s: stringArray)
    System.out.println(s);
```

With your given json, the output is this:

```
"images (3).jpg"  
"images (4).jpg"
"474harvester2008C-525x328.jpg"
```

Comment: How do i split them?

Comment: @KritiJain They are splitted in `stringArray[0], stringArray[1], stringArray[2] `